# Connection reset when accessing website through Apache HTTP Connections

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying out this example http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java

However, it is giving me the following:

```
Feb 13, 2012 1:40:55 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
Feb 13, 2012 1:40:55 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
```

I access the web through a proxy, not sure if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) has a proxy example.

Comment: Hi Brettw, yes i saw that page and tried out without success, have you  any experience with proxies with Apache Http Connector?